# Given a tuple of method signatures, is it possible to infer a new tuple type of which values are the return values of the original tuple methods?

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

In TypeScript, I have this tuple type:

```
type MyTuple = [(value: string) => string, (value: string) => number];
```

How can I infer the following new type from the above?

```
// [string, number]
```

I'm aware of TypeScript's `ReturnType` type, however I don't know how to use this with an array/tuple, or if it's even possible.

I'm needing to use this in conjunction with generics if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this!  TypeScript 3.1 saw the introduction of support for [mapped tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).  Since that release, when you use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) on an array or a tuple, you get a new array or tuple which acts on the element types.  So, here you go:

```
type MyTuple = [(value: string) => string, (value: string) => number];

type MapReturnType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never
};

type ReturnTuple = MapReturnType<MyTuple>;
// type ReturnTuple = [string, number]
```

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MyTuple%20%3D%20%5B(value%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%2C%20(value%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20number%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20MapReturnType%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20(...args%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20infer%20R%20%3F%20R%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20ReturnTuple%20%3D%20MapReturnType%3CMyTuple%3E%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20type%20ReturnTuple%20%3D%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D)

Looks good.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!